# TypoScript Persistence Mapping in Model

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-8.x

(Used TYPO3 v8.7.9)

I've overwritten the tableName of a model like:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Test\Data\Domain\Model\ContactAddress {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tx_data_domain_model_contact_address
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In another model I use this model in an @var like here:

```
    /**
     * address
     *
     * @var \Test\Data\Domain\Model\ContactAddress
     * @lazy
     */
    protected $address = null;
```

This configuration throws the error
`Table 'database.tx_data_domain_model_contactaddress' doesn't exist`

Does this configuration not work for such use cases?
I've cleared all sorts of caches.

Comment: Seems that the table does not exist. Did you check this?

Comment: Another thing: Use `@lazy` annotation only for ObjectStorages, not for direct relations.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Thanks, I've changed the @lazy part. The table does not exist, thats correct, but the new table with `contact_address` exist. I've debugged a lot and found out that the datamap is created wrong because he `web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapFactory.php:129` is empty.

Comment: When you set a table to map, it must exist.